# If applying a nilpotent operator first time kills n dimensions, does that mean applying it again will kill another n dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra

If applying a nilpotent operator the first time kills n dimensions, does that mean applying it again will kill another n dimensions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No. Consider for example the linear map $N:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that sends every element to zero. It "kills" everything ($n$ dimensions) in the first step, but nothing in the second: $\mathbb{R}^n = \ker (N) = \ker (N^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - consider the matrix

$$ \begin{align*}
M &= \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \right] \\
M^2 &= \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right] \\
M^3 &= \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right] \\
M^4 &= 0
\end{align*} $$

The null space of $M$ has dimension 2, but applying it twice is applying $M^2$, and its null space has dimension 3, not 4.